# Append a block within the flow of multiple page pdf

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

My scenario:
- I am using Antenna house XSL Formatter
- Multiple page PDF generation divided into two columns in all pages 
**- I want to add a block(disclaimer) in the 2nd column of the first page inside the body-region.**

It should look the same way the image depicts.
Please provide me the solution or references if possible.
[image: This is a page-1 layout where I need to append a disclaimer block within the data flow]
[image: This is the layout of the rest of the pages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH Formatter V6.0 is capable of arranging the float content in an arbitrary place of the page, arranging the float content in multi-column layout with column spanning of the float. As a result, AH Formatter V6.0 can meet various demands of the arrangement while formatting the document with the illustration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used an alternative way to allow a disclaimer within the flow of data by passing a flag through my data xml.

Thanks though!